# EditText losing focus if I hit the record button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, chat

I'm trying to build chat interface . I've written code for recording voice with animation for the fab.my problem is when I press the button and my edittext is focused the edittext for no reason is losing focus which is hiding the autodetect words bar in the keyboard leaving the Fab above the keyboard with 1 cm . I know that this problem is due to the recycle view since when i just set the visibility of the recycler view to Gone the edittext don't lose focus when I try to record .I've tried also to change windowSoftInputMode.  Thanks for the help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_chat_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        >



    <com.example.fcb.insurance.customViews.holdingbutton.HoldingButtonLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:hbl_cancel_icon="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
        app:hbl_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:hbl_holding_view="@+id/start_record"
        app:hbl_icon="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp"
        app:hbl_radius="@dimen/activity_main_holding_button_radius"
        app:hbl_second_radius="@dimen/activity_main_holding_button_second_radius"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessage"
       android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slide_to_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_main_slide_to_cancel_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_main_slide_to_cancel_margin_right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_main_slide_to_cancel_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_main_slide_to_cancel_icon_size"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_main_slide_to_cancel_icon_margin_right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_main_slide_to_cancel_icon_margin_right"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label_slide_to_cancel"/>

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/textView_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"

            android:minHeight="@dimen/activity_main_input_holder_min_height"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_main_input_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_main_input_margin_left"
               android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hint_type_your_message"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_main_input_padding_vertical"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_main_input_padding_vertical"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_main_input_text_size"
                android:background="@drawable/chat_input_text"
                android:maxLines="6"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                ></EditText>




            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/start_record"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />



        </LinearLayout>

  </com.example.fcb.insurance.customViews.holdingbutton.HoldingButtonLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/sendMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"

        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_chat_item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/input_holder"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_chat_list_out"

        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your onclick event

```
YOUR_EDITTEXT.requestFocus()
```

Comment: try to make it 
android:focusable="true"
in your XML

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution . I wrapped the recyclerView with linearLayout and I disabled focus and blocked the descendants.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/input_holder"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_chat_item_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_chat_list_out"

    />
</LinearLayout>
```